# Is Polymorphism a waste to apply for the classes that we exactly know the type prior run-time?

Tags: oop, polymorphism, runtime, compile-time, object-oriented-analysis

**Run-time Polymorphism** can be used to let the run-time to dynamically load  the exact concrete class of an abstract class/interface. (You can take Animal/Dog, Vehicle/Car examples)

But when we know the exact concrete class @coding-time (compile-time), does it really need to forcefully apply polymorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I write OO code, I tend to use most-general type I can on the left-hand side of the assignment. This immediately means that my answer to your question is - no.

Here's the example:

```
Animal x = new Dog();
...
x.move();
```

The reason why I'm doing this is that I'm probably going to split beginning and end of the operation into two distinct operations. My methods are extremely short in practice.

Applied to the same example:

```
function moveDog() {
    move(new Dog());
}

function move(Animal animal) {
    animal.move();
}
```

As you can see, it would make no sense for the move function to know what kind of animal it is really moving.

Generally, it is compiler's duty to figure whether in a given code base any concrete call has been made with an overridden move() method. Some compilers can detect that no overridden method will be subjected to them and then they remove dynamic dispatch at compile time. With some luck, my code above would compile the same whether move function receives Animal or Dog.

Now, this is theory. In practice, there are two important things. First, compilers that are widely used have still not started using such aggressive optimization techniques as detecting static method calls, as opposed to calls that require dynamic dispatch. Second, the first thing doesn't matter too much with CPU power we have today.

I have been writing highly optimized code for fifteen years already and I have met the situation in which I had to factor polymorphic calls out. That is why I strongly recommend to apply polymorphism as much as possible. When the time comes to add some classes, to incorporate new features, polymorphic calls will likely be the tool to seamlessly add new classes to the existing design. If you used overly concrete types during development, it could easily happen that you cannot add new feature to the given code base.

Comment: interesting explanation. But I have two question. (1) If some concrete class has a method that is not there in parent class, and you want to call that, what will happen? (2) Are you suggesting that polymorphism waste CPU time?

Comment: (1) Then you have to hold a reference to an object of a derived class; if, however, you only need common features and wish to be able to redefine them, then hold a reference to the base type to cover all cases. (2) Dynamic dispatch, which is the mechanism used to implement polymorphism certainly costs in CPU cycles - one old research concluded that some 30% of all CPU time spent on calling functions in an application was spent resolving function addresses; but again, that is such a small portion of all the time that it doesn't matter in practice.

Answer (score 1):

> But when we know the exact concrete class @coding-time (compile-time), does it really need to forcefully apply polymorphism?

Knowing the type at compile time is not necessarily a yes/no thing across all the code in an app and an object's entire lifetime, given techniques for type erasure.  But, ignoring those classic uses of polymorphism, there are still other potential reasons such as...

- (sorry - pretty obvious one this) to make it easier to change the implementation should another become available later
- to make it easier to "mock" an implementation for testing (i.e. provide objects that pretend to provide some service or function, but have more scripted/controllable/observable behaviours to let tests put some dependent code through its paces)
- hide aspects of the implementation that might otherwise have to be exposed (e.g. in C++, a class/struct definition must declare all the protected and private members)

  - this is sometimes for Intellectual Property protection; at other times, so more changes can be made to the implementation without having to make a change the "header" file that would typically trigger recompilation of a lot of dependent code
- to aid in modelling and application design, using the "interfaces" to cleanly specify the intended APIs, which can then provide a more stable reference for comparison as the implementations are fleshed out