# factory vs factory method pattern in c#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, factory-pattern, factory-method

Could anyone help me to understand the the following queries regarding factory method pattern?

im refering [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kalisk/factory-method-design-pattern-using-C-Sharp/) link as a sample.

1.what is the need of abstract class Factory in factory method pattern? What
            if use a normal class?

2.It is stated that change in the code will not affect the client. But 
    if A  new class product3 has been added, an appropriate
            change will be required in the client code also.(as per the below code). Then what is the advantage of this design pattern?

3.What is the benefit of `objFactories[0] = new concreteFactoryforProduct1();` over `concreteFactoryforProduct1 factory = new concreteFactoryforProduct1();`

```
    Factory[] objFactories = new Factory[2]; 
    objFactories[0] = new concreteFactoryforProduct1(); 
    objFactories[1] = new concreteFactoryforProduct2(); 
    foreach (Factory objFactory in objFactories) 

     { 
            Product objProduct = objFactory.GetProduct(); 
            objProduct.GetDetails(); 
        }
```

4.Why we cant implement open close principle in simple design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) As per the simplest use of abstract classes, adding abstract avoids creating instances using new Factory(). (Because it is not meaningful, same as animal and elephant -> animal is only an abstraction, no entity exist called animal)

(2) It is just a demo. There will no use case on earth to list down the available factories.

(3) In the example, It's a Factory array, your question is not applicable.

(4) I think you are asking about a situation without using Factory method pattern. There can be a lot of situations. You can identify if you try to implement it.

Comment: 1) but im creating instances objFactories[0] = new concreteFactoryforProduct1();  2) im not clear what you try to explain. 3) why should i use  objFactories[0] there?  why cant I use the class instance? what is the advantage?

Comment: (1) Yes, that is OK, You are not calling new Factory() -> constructor. Just the reference type. (2) In practice if u want an object created by Factory1, you just create an instance (preferably Singleton) and call its method. (3) In here,  without that how you can insert both types of concrete factories in the same array?

Comment: I understood your point. But you are explaining the pattern implementation and im asking the advantage of using this way. Only this example it uses array. You can have many example which directly assign to factory abstract instance.

Comment: @TomCruise I think you are asking about (3). I got your point. One advantage of using abstraction is this. Get this as an example. `Factory myFactory = new concreteFactoryforProcuct1();` Because your reference type is `Factory` you can do something like this if you want in future. `myFactory = new concreteFactoryforProcuct2();` And you can also refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006956/is-polymorphism-a-waste-to-apply-for-the-classes-that-we-exactly-know-the-type-p asked by me. :)